# Is the NSSet iteration needed in this case?

Tags: objective-c, nsset

I have a NSSet of object from the same class and I want to get the property value for each object stored in the NSSet, do I always need to iterate through the NSSet ? Or can I somehow create another NSSet containing the properties of the objects only without iterating?

If I have a NSSet of strings, and I need to remove the same substring from all strings in the NSSet, do I need to iterate, or can I create another NSSet with the removed substrings in another way ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling your [NSSet's](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) `valueForKey:`.  It returns a set of the property of every item in your set.

This requires every object in the set to be KVC compliant.

Comment: It is actually pretty hard not to be KVC-compliant for any message it actually responds to.